# What is the best way to propagate event to top most Widget/QMainWindow in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a layered kind of architecture, in which one Widget is inside another.
Top most object is QMainWindow, and there can be any numbers of internal widgets (one inside another).
example:- mainwindow is parent of widget1, widget1 is parent of widget2..so on..

Now I need to handle the close event of the latest child in the top most window.
I want to know the best way of achieving it in QT 5.7.

Comment: What do you mean by handle the close event? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to do something in the top most window when the latest child is closed. I may want to override the closeEvent handler of the top most window (if it is a good approach), but then I need to know how to propogate the close event upto the top most Widget/mainWindow.

Comment: Main windows are closed, so how are you triggering close events on the childs in the first place? Please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to subclass the QMainWindow and override the `childEvent` function:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#childEvent

Would allow you to do something like:

```
class TarunsMainWindow : QMainWindow {
protected:
    void childEvent(QChildEvent event) override {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved) {
            // do something special
        }

        QMainWindow::childEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to catch the child removal event in the immediate parent by your method but I need to do it in the top most window/widget. I even tried to ignore the event in immediate parent hoping that the event would propagate to ancestors. But this did not work.

Comment: What youre suggesting should work with this design if all parents are hooked up properly... maybe you're not setting a parent properly somewhere?